# Efficiency on Project Euler Problem #8

Tags: python, programming-challenge

I am doing Project Euler problem #8:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> ```
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
> ```
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

Here is my code to this problem:

```
L = []
L.append("73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934")
L.append("96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843")
L.append("85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511")
L.append("12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557")
L.append("66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113")
L.append("62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749")
L.append("30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866")
L.append("70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776")
L.append("65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243")
L.append("52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397")
L.append("53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482")
L.append("83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474")
L.append("82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881")
L.append("16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586")
L.append("17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042")
L.append("24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408")
L.append("07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188")
L.append("84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606") 
L.append("05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725")
L.append("71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450")

M = []

for s in L:
    for i in list(s): M.append(i)

greatest_product = 0

for i in range(len(M)):
    product = 1
    substring = M[i:i+13]
    for digit in substring: 
        product*=int(digit)
    if product > greatest_product:
        greatest_product = product

print greatest_product
```

The code works, but how would I improve the efficiency?

Answer (score 9):

- The loop iterates over the whole `range(len(M))`. It means that the last few products exercise less than 13 digits. It doesn't matter in this particular example (they are all zeros anyway), but may lead to erroneous result in general case. Iterate over `range(len(M) - 13)`.
- Digit-to-int conversion happens 13 times for each digit. Better convert them once in a separate loop before doing calculations.
- Every time a 0 is encountered, you may safely skip the whole bunch of digits: the product will be 0 anyway.
- A sliding window technique may help.

In pseudocode:

```
product *= data[head]
product /= data[tail]
head += 1
tail += 1
```

(be careful to not divide by 0).

Answer (score 1):

As the question was about improving the efficiency I'd like to point out that the search can be limited to smaller strings.

As was pointed out the 0s will always produce a product of 0. Keeping that in mind you can see that you only need to search the string between the zeros.

Following this train of thought further optimizations come naturally:

- only strings longer than 13 digits can apply
- as these strings no longer contain zeros the sliding window suggested by @vnp will work without checking for 0

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the nested for loop as it is not needed.

If you're familiar with the problem of finding \$k\$th last element in the single linked list then you can borrow same idea for this problem.

Hint: let's say you are checking some 13 digits starting at index \$i\$ till \$i+12\$, and its product is \$P\$. To check the product of the next combination of 13 digits, you just need to divide \$P\$ by \$i\$th digit and multiply it by \$i+13\$th digit, and so on, just keep in mind: edge cases.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.