# Answer to an implementation of Project Euler #8

Tags: python, optimization, beginner, programming-challenge, python-2.x

I saw that there was a [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58535/efficiency-on-project-euler-problem-8) asking to review an answer to the Project Euler question #8. My answer didn't look anything like the answer in that question and as a beginner, I was wondering if someone would take a look at my answer and let me know if there is anything I could improve upon.

```
#Project Euler #8

'''
The four adjacent digits in the 100 digit number that have the greatest
product are 9x9x8x9 = 5832.

Find the 13 adjacent digits in the 1000 digit number that have the 
greatest product
'''


n = '\
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'

#Import Modules
import operator
from operator import mul

#Put all of the 
def greatest_product():
    global list
    list = []
    for i in n:
        list.append(int(i))
    return list

greatest_product()

def lists():
    global seq_13
    seq_13 = []

    count = 0
    for i in list:
        x = list[count:count+13]
        if len(x) == 13:
            seq_13.append(x)
            count += 1
    return seq_13
print lists()

num_list_fin = []
for num_item in seq_13:
    num_item_u = [reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, num_item)]
    num_item_u.append(num_item)
    num_list_fin.append(num_item_u)

num_list_fin.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
print num_list_fin[len(num_list_fin)-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename your variables and functions to be more specific and do not keep unneeded array data, like so:

```
def createDigits():
    global digits
    digits = []
    for i in n:
        digits.append(int(i))
    return digits

def calculateProduct(startPosition):
   global digits
   global windowSize
   factors = digits[startPosition: startPosition+windowSize]
   product = 1
   for digit in digits:
       product = product * digit
   return product

createDigits()
maxProduct = 1
windowSize = 13
for i in xrange(0, len(digits - windowSize))
   product = calculateProduct(i)
   if product > maxProduct:
      maxProduct = product
```

EDIT: Also, might as well not scan products at the end when the window starts to shrink, since they are guaranteed to be less than the last complete window.

Answer (score 2):

### General issues

- **Stray imports:** You never use `operator` and `mul` (though `mul` could have been useful).
- **Poor function names:** The `greatest_product()` function is misnamed: its task is to convert a string into a list of digits.  The `lists()` function could also be named more descriptively — I suggest `consecutive_groups()`.
- **Use of global variables:** Function should take input parameters and return its results.  Instead, you implicitly take the inputs from the environment and pass the results back via global variables.  (You *wrote* the code with `return`s, but in practice you are relying on global variables instead.)

Reorganizing the code based on just the points above…

```
def digits(numeric_string):
    list = []
    for i in n:
        list.append(int(i))
    return list

def consecutive_groups(chunk_size, list):
    sequences = []

    count = 0
    for i in list:
        x = list[count:count+chunk_size]
        if len(x) == 13:
            sequences.append(x)
            count += 1
    return sequences

n = '…'
seq_13 = consecutive_groups(13, digits(n))
…
```

It's clearer how `seq_13` is derived when the code uses functions as intended rather than relying on side effects.

### List handling

You build a lot of lists, starting with an empty list `[]` and `.append()`ing entries to them.  In Python, that can be better expressed as a list comprehension.

```
def digits(numeric_string):
    return [int(i) for i in n]

def consecutive_groups(chunk_size, list):
    return [list[count:count+chunk_size] for count in xrange(len(list) - chunk_size)]
```

To find the maximum product, you don't need to sort; just use the [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function.  Conveniently, `max()` lets you specify a criterion via a function.

```
def product(list):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, list)

n = '…'
seq_13 = consecutive_groups(13, digits(n))
print max(seq_13, key=product)
```