# Python Find the N adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, comparative-review

This question was presented to me, adapted from Project Euler #8.  The goal is to find the N adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product.  Range of N: 10 <= N <= 50.  Not only I have to find the max product of 13 consecutive digits in a sequence, I also had to find the max product of 19, 35, 46. This is really no biggie, just scaling up from the previous 13. Anyway, I set out to code two solutions, one which is done by a generator ( I love these efficient things, so useful in Project Euler) and another which I would describe it as code I written before I knew about generators.

Code 1 (Generator):

> number=7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

```
def largestproduct(adjdigit):
    x=0
    y=adjdigit
    z=str(number)[x:y]
    product=1
    count=0
    while y<=1000:
        for i in z:
            if count==adjdigit:
                yield product
                product=1
                count=0
                x+=1
                y+=1
                z=str(number)[x:y]
            product*=int(i)
            count+=1
print(max(largestproduct(13)))
```

Code 2 (Non-generator):

> number=7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

```
def largestproduct(adjdigit):
    x=0
    y=adjdigit
    z=str(number)[x:y]
    product=1
    count=0
    control=0
    while y<=1000:
        for i in z:
            if count==adjdigit:
                if product>control:
                    control=product
                product=1
                count=0
                x+=1
                y+=1
                z=str(number)[x:y]

            product*=int(i)
            count+=1
    return control
print(largestproduct(19))
```

Which one would be better and more efficient to use? To me, generators are always the best due to them lacking the need to occupy tons of space in memory when processing large amounts of data. Oh and please suggest improvements, and cool functions and tools that can be useful from other Python packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Review

Yes the first option would be better as memory might become an issue with really long numbers (say you have a 10 million length number). But that implementation could be improved as well

- Your first solution does not return the max product but rather a <strike>list</strike> generator of products. This is confusing!
- Chop up your code into functions, as it makes it easier to test/change things

The problem can be divided into to 3 seperate functions:

1. Cut a big number into evenly sized chunks of adjacent digits
2. Sum the product of the chunks
3. A main function that returns the largest adjecent product

## Alternative Code

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def cut_adj_chunks(iterable, chunk_size):
    for i in range(len(iterable) - chunk_size):
        yield iterable[i:i+chunk_size]

def sum_prod(num_str):
    num_list = map(int, num_str)
    return reduce(operator.mul, num_list, 1)

def largest_prod(adj_digits, big_num):
    return max(sum_prod(chunk) for chunk in cut_adj_chunks(str(big_num), adj_digits))
```

Comment: Your right, that is definitely confusing. Thanks for the answer, very useful to know :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Coding style

There is a well-established coding style for Python, the 
[PEP8 coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
and conformance to that style can be checked online at
[PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com).

In your case it reports “missing space around operator” in almost every
code line.

#### Variable names

`x`, `y`, `z` are meaningless variable names, and `adjdigit` isn't
self-explaining either.

#### Magic numbers

The number `1000` in

```
while y<=1000:
```

is the string length – which might not be obvious to the reader, and is
error-prone if you change the given number. It should be *computed* from
the string instead.

#### Global variables

You pass the number of adjacent digits as an argument to the function,
but the big number itself is a global variable. Passing *both* parameters
to the function makes it easier to add unit tests.

#### Simplify the program logic

You reset `count`, `product`, and `z` each time *after* a product is computed,
this seems unnecessary complicated to me.

```
    z = str(number)[x:y]
    product = 0
    for i in z:
        product *= int(i)
    yield product
```

would be easier to understand and also makes the `count` variable obsolete.

The iteration over all possible start/end positions is better done with
a for loop.

#### Avoid unnecessary conversions

In your code, the big number is converted to a string repeatedly, it would be
sufficient to convert it only once. You could even provide the given number as
a string directly.

The substring `z` is also not needed because we can access a character from
the original string directly.

#### Putting it together

Summarizing the suggested changes so far, the generator-based version could
look like this:

```
def products(number, num_digits):
    for start_index in range(0, len(number) - num_digits):
        product = 1
        for i in range(start_index, start_index + num_digits):
            product *= int(number[i])
        yield product


def max_product(number, num_digits):
    return max(products(number, num_digits))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    large_number = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969" \
        "8352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949" \
        "4954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329" \
        "0963295227443043557668966489504452445231617318564030987111217223" \
        "8311362229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749303589072" \
        "9629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908" \
        "7922749219016997208880937766572733300105336788122023542180975125" \
        "4540594752243525849077116705560136048395864467063244157221553975" \
        "3697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570" \
        "5605749026140797296865241453510047482166370484403199890008895243" \
        "4506585412275886668811642717147992444292823086346567481391912316" \
        "2824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902" \
        "2671055626321111109370544217506941658960408071984038509624554443" \
        "6298123098787992724428490918884580156166097919133875499200524063" \
        "6899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972" \
        "571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
    print(max(products(large_number, 13)))
```

#### To generate or not to generate ...

I don't think there is much difference with respect to efficiency.
Your second “non-generator” version does not occupy more space because
each product is immediately compared against the current maximum, and not
stored in a list.

The advantage of the generator-based version is that the two tasks

- generating all possible products,
- determining the maximum

are clearly separated.

#### Performance improvements

Every substring is converted to a number by iterating over all of its
characters. This can be improved by *updating* the product instead,
this “sliding windows technique” is described for example in

- [Efficiency on Project Euler Problem #8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58535/efficiency-on-project-euler-problem-8/58539#58539)
- [Project Euler #8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82976/project-euler-8/82977#82977)